# Why mesh created with ThreeBSP.js is not working properly with any material other than MeshNormalMaterial?

Tags: javascript, three.js, threecsg

The dice looks like a dice only if I use `MeshNormalMaterial` in the second last line (`result = resultBSP.toMesh(materialNormal);`). With any other material it just looks like a cube with no `subtraction` (dots) on it. The `ThreeBSP` (ThreeCSG upgrade) library I am using is located [here](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG/blob/master/ThreeCSG.js).
There is no problem with using the `MeshNormalMaterial`. It just doesn't have almost any options to modify it. (It doesn't take parameters like other materials).

Here is my function that I am using to create a dice:

```
function buildDice(){

    var materialNormal = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    var diceCube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100), materialNormal);
    
    diceCube.position.x = 0;
    diceCube.position.y = 50;
    diceCube.position.z = 0;
    
    diceCube.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    diceCube.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
    var cubeBSP = new ThreeBSP(diceCube);
    
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(75,16,8);
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, materialNormal);
    
    sphereMesh.scale.x = 0.17;
    sphereMesh.scale.y = 0.17;
    sphereMesh.scale.z = 0.17;
    
    //coords of the spheres 
    var xPositions = [....]; // coordinates for xPositions of sphereMesh
    var yPositions = [....];
    var zPositions = [....];
    
            
    var diceDots    = new THREE.Geometry();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++){
        
        sphereMesh.position.x   = xPositions[i];
        sphereMesh.position.y   = yPositions[i];
        sphereMesh.position.z   = zPositions[i];
        THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(diceDots, sphereMesh);
    }
    
    var dotsMesh = new THREE.Mesh(diceDots, materialNormal);
    dotsMesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    dotsMesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    
    var dotsBSP = new ThreeBSP(dotsMesh);
    var resultBSP = cubeBSP.subtract(dotsBSP);
    
    result = resultBSP.toMesh(materialNormal);
    scene.add(result);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work with other Materials, for example with a `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`. This jsfiddle using your `buildDice()`-function may help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/152/

[image]

You have to update the mesh´s matrix before merging the geometry, and best not to use deprecated functions for this.

Three.js r73

Comment: So if it is just the matter of using geometry utils then my dice shouldn't work with any material right? How come it works with meshnormalmaterial and not with any other material?

Comment: Also i navigated camera to the middle of the dice and was able to see that the dice itself is actually working fine. The depressions are there on each surface. They are just not appearing from the outside. I tried many different combinations of directional and point lights but the depressions on the surfaces are just not appearing. I am 100% sure they are there.

Comment: Your code _is_ working already with other Materials than ```MeshNormalMaterial```, I added a screenshot of the jsfiddle.

Comment: For some reason it is not working in my project. Which means there  is something up with my init() function. Most probably some lighting issue. I am going to compare my init with yours to see what am I doing different. Final week of school is stressful. To many things going on.

Comment: That's it. The freaking lights man. My code always worked correctly. It's the lights that kept messing things up and I never doubted that. THANKS A LOT. I really appreciate you looking into my code.